# How can my RSU call a function at periodic time intervals in Veins?

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I am currently working on an algorithm on Veins 4.7.1 where many vehicles and a RSU are sending and receiving messages.

I would like now my RSU to perform **periodic calculations** regardless if it sended or received a message. The problem is I don't know how and where to implement these periodic calculations in my RSU application.

My first attempt was to implement the calculations in one of the functions provided in `BaseWaveApplLayer`. I though about adding them in `handlePositionUpdate(cObject* obj)` with a timer, but I obviously cannot use this function in the RSU application.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What about sending a self message at specific intervalls?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems I had some misunderstandings about the message processing so far. It has now become clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using self messages is typical way of doing periodic task in a module. However, it might be problematic if you need to do several tasks. You need to create all messages first, handle them correctly and remember to `cancelAndDelete` them in a destructor.

You can achieve the same result with less code using Veins utility called `TimerManager` (added in Veins 4.7.). You need to have a member of `TimerManager` in the module and specify tasks in `initialize`. The advantage is that if you decide to add new periodic tasks later, it is as simple as adding them in `initialize` and `TimerManager` will take care of everything else. It might look like this:

```
class TraCIDemoRSU11p : public DemoBaseApplLayer {
public:
    void initialize(int stage) override;
    // ...
protected:
    veins::TimerManager timerManager{this};  // define and instantiate the TimerManager
    // ...
};
```

And `initialize`

```
void TraCIDemoRSU11p::initialize(int stage) {
    if (stage == 0) {       // Members and pointers initialization       
    }
    else if (stage == 1) {  // Members that require initialized other modules           
        // encode the reaction to the timer firing with a lambda
        auto recurringCallback = [this](){
            //Perform Calculations
        };
        // specify when and how ofthen a timer shall fire
        auto recurringTimerSpec = veins::TimerSpecification(recurringCallback).interval(1);
        // register the timer with the TimerManager instance
        timerManager.create(recurringTimerSpec, "recurring timer");
    }
}
```

Read more in the manual on Github: [TimerManager manual](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/doc/manual/timermanager.md). The code with comments is taken from there.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved my problem thanks to [Ventu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959871/ventu)'s comment.
I simply created a wsm inherented message type in `BaseApplLayer.h` and implemented the following code in `TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc`

```
void TraCIDemoRSU11p::initialize(int stage) {
    MyBaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);
    if (stage == 0) {       // Members and pointers initialization       
    }
    else if (stage == 1) {  // Members that require initialized other modules           
        // Message Scheduling
        scheduleAt(simTime(), sendSelfMsgEvt);
    }
}

void TraCIDemoRSU11p::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) {
    switch (msg->getKind()) {
    case SELF_MSG_EVT: {
        std::cout << "RSU Self Message received at " << simTime().dbl() << std::endl;  
        // Perform Calculations
        // ...

        // Self Message sending:
        scheduleAt(simTime() + PERIOD, sendSelfMsgEvt);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        if (msg)
            DBG_APP << "APP: Error: Got Self Message of unknown kind! Name: "
                << msg->getName() << endl;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```